# How do you extract a smaller grid out of a larger grid to prevent overlapping of the grids?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

[image]

Hello!

I am trying to create a single grid with multiple denser grids towards the center. I initially thought of using the loop cut tool but those cuts go from one side of the plane to the other, making it impossible for me to achieve this denser grid inside a grid kind of result.

As things are currently, if I were to merge them, the grids would all overlap within each other rather than to have a smooth stepping inside of each grids unique area, so simply joining them together didn't work out for me.

I am looking for a way to "cut out" the shape of the smaller grids from the bigger grid, to effectively only have one grid fill out each of the spaces, to then merge them together into one coherent, stepping grid.

None of the search queries I could think of resulted in me being able to solve this, so I figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 0):

you could try it with geometry nodes:

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

i start with a grid with 3x3 faces.

In the node group i am checking the absolute x and y values, whether they are less than a certain value (the middle), if yes, i subdivide that. Than outside the node group a scale the whole mesh so that i can reuse my node group again.

some more steps:

[image]